# Regex to match invalid CSV line with unescaped quotes

Tags: regex, csv

Let's say I have a file of strings like

```
11,"abc","def"
12,"ab "c"","def" // invalid
13,"ab,"c"","def" // invalid
14,""a" b,c","def" // invalid
15,""a", "b"c","def" // invalid
```

As you can see some of the double quotes are unescaped. I'd like to filter out invalid strings before I try to parse them.

I'm thinking to do something like `\,\".+\"\,` to find a token and then to check that it doesn't contain `","` inside. But I can't figure out how to make it work.

I've searched in SO but haven't found an answer which works for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Just in case - I'd prefer a java compatible solution.

Comment: could you add expected output? for example for: `13,"ab,"c"","def"`

Comment: This is probably not a problem you should be solving just with regexes; it'll be much easier to write a parser handling a column at a time. Assuming you don't have to handle arbitrarily malformed input (i.e. that your invalid inputs have some pattern) it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @m.cekiera I'd like ignore invalid strings.

Comment: @cyrillk you mean, that `,` is always beetwen different values, or that it could also be inside strings?

Comment: @m.cekiera It can be inside some strings.

Answer (score 1):

If String always start and end with `"`, you can try with this Java regex:

```
(?<=,\s{0,99}"|(?!\A)\G)[^"]+|(?<=(?!\A)\G|")(")(?!\s*[,\n]|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iV5aK4/1)

the group 1 capture invalid quotes, you can get the indices with `matcher.start(1)` and `matcher.end(1)`. `\s{0,99}` will work only in Java.

Comment: Thank you! Why does it highlight all the lines?

Comment: @cyrillk because it match the not-`"` characters after comma and `"`, or `"` sign if it follows already matched text which and it is not followed by comma. the first match (non - `"` characters) is to find only '`' marks inside a String. Also in Regex101 the `\s{0,99}` will not work, so one example is not highlighted, but in Java it will work